# using the syscall mount() to remount ext4 filesystem read-only

Tags: c, kernel, mount, system-calls

I want to write a simple C program with hardcoded options, which does nothing else than remount root filesystem to `read-only`

I see, the mount() syscall takes following parameters:

```
mount(const char *spec, const char *node, const char *type, int flags, void *data)
```

I have following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return mount ("/dev/sda1", "/", "ext4", "MS_RDONLY", NULL);
}
```

I know, in place of `MS_RDONLY` I should use a type `int`. But where do I find the value corresponding to `MS_RDONLY` (or which ever option I need to use) ?

Comment: as others pointed out, `MS_RDONLY` is defined in `sys/mount.h`. Your code will not work, however, unless you add `MS_REMOUNT` to flags (`MS_RDONLY | MS_REMOUNT`).

Comment: @mfro - you are right. It works with `MS_RDONLY | MS_REMOUNT`. Are these flags enough, or do I need to specify some more? How can I print the flags of the currently mounted filesystem ?

Comment: and what is the purpose of the last parameter (the void pointer) which in my example is `NULL`

Comment: you can pass the options arguments you give to `mount(8)` through `data` as string. These are dependent of the filesystem type, but with `MS_REMOUNT`, the active options are preserved.

Comment: @mfro - I am experiencing strange problems: When I remount my filesystem using `MS_RDONLY | MS_REMOUNT` flags, symlinks suddenly seem to stop working. Do you know why that would be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS_RDONLY should be defined in mount.h, that you already included in your code. Changing `"MS_RDONLY"` to `MS_RDONLY` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's `#define`'d in `sys/mount.h`.

```
mount ("/dev/sda1", "/", "ext4", MS_RDONLY, NULL);
```